# main content wrapper div get's pushed down the page in IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer

I have a 2 column layout, with the left side for navigation and the right side for the main content.

The right side content has a wrapper div that looks like:

```
<div id="content">
```

Now this looks fine in FF and GC, and it IE but if I change the padding to anything over 4px that section gets pushed down below the left navigation.

```
#content
{
    padding:3px;   // 4 makes it get pushed down
}
```

Does this mean IE has a different way of calculating the width of all my elements?
Is this a common problem that has a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

How wide is your two-column-container, and how wide are the left column and right columns?

I suspect you are making the right column too wide to float next to the left column inside the container.

Comment: for some reason, if I set 'width=100%' then the content div doesnt' get pushed down in IE anymore.

Comment: if you also set overflow:auto then the container will stretch to the bottom of the two floated inner divs, too :D